# How to get rid of if-else conditions in code

Tags: c#, if-statement, design-patterns

I want create some console application. This application will work by parameters from input args[] array.

Like this: `> app.exe -arg1 -arg2 -arg3:str3 -arg4:str4 -arg5 etc.`

Where `-arg1, -arg2, -arg5` the parameters for initialization variables in my app. The `-arg3:str3 and -arg4:str4` the parameters with any string.

For example, if I sent the `-arg1` then in my app I need initialization the `var1` by any string. Like this:

```
foreach (string s in args)
{
    if(s.contains("-arg1")) someString1 = "someVal1";
    if(s.contains("-arg2")) someString2 = "someVal2";
    if(s.contains("-arg5")) someString5 = "someVal5";
    if(s.contains("-arg3")) someString3 = s.split(':')[1];
    if(s.contains("-arg4")) someString4 = s.split(':')[1];
}
```

I think that my solution is bad, because I need to test every argument in a loop and if I want to pass more new parameters I have to add new conditions.

Tell me please, maybe there are specific approaches to solving my problem?
Or maybe there is some design pattern for such tasks?

**EDIT:** I can't use any libraries

Comment: If you are only concerned about the cmd line arguments, then there are some decent libraries.

Comment: @Santhos, of course, on SO, we do not allow folk to ask for library recommendations... ;)

Comment: @DavidArno: that is why it is not an answer but just a comment... ;)

Comment: @Santhos,@DavidArno,@JamesThorpe I see this answers, but I can't use any libraries

Comment: @netwer Note that one of the answers uses things provided by Microsoft in the framework

Comment: @netwer, why can't you use libraries?

Comment: @DavidArno This is one of the requirements for the solution to this task

Comment: @netwer - your best bet then is to post the question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and explain it's an assignment and that therefore you need a self-contained answer. That site is designed specifically for helping folk improve their code.

Comment: @DavidArno ok, thanks. I listened to your recommendations

Comment: @DavidArno This code is stripped of context and will be closed as off-topic for being "example code" on CR.